# How submit flink programs to a cluster from another flink program?

Tags: apache-flink

I wanna run flink programs on demand submit them went one conditions happens. How run flink jobs from java code in flink 1.3.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flink's REST API to submit a job from another running Flink job. For more details see the [REST API documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html#submitting-programs).

Comment: I just have a problem passing multiple arguments to a program in my run query. Could you show me an example

Comment: Could you solve your problem with multiple arguments? Otherwise it might make sense to open an issue for it.